# Oracle: How can I get a value 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' comparing two NUMBERS in a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to compare two numbers. Let's take i.e. 1 and 2.

I've tried to write the following query but it simply doesn't work as expected (Toad says: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected):

```
SELECT 1 > 2 from dual
```

The DECODE is something like a Switch case, so how can I get the result of an expression evalutation (i.e. a number comparison) putting it in the select list?

I have found a solution using a functions instead of an expression in the SELECT LIST: i.e.

```
select DECODE(SIGN(actual - target)
           , -1, 'NO Bonus for you'
           , 0,'Just made it'
           , 1, 'Congrats, you are a winner')
from some_table
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Also how do I compare two dates?

Comment: I've found a solution using FUNCTIONS instead of EXPRESSION in the SELECT LIST: i.e. DECODE(SIGN(actual-target), -1, 'NO Bonus for you', 0,'Just made it', 1, 'Congrats, you are a winner').
Are there more elegant way?

AND how do I compare two date

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant info, instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: comparison between integer in select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494955/oracle-comparison-between-integer-in-select-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SIGN()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions145.htm) function is indeed probably the best way of classifying (in)equality that may be of interest to you if you want to test a > b, a = b and a < b, and it will accept date-date or numeric-numeric as an argument.

I'd use a Case statement by preference, rather than a decode.

```
Select
  case sign(actual-target)
    when -1 then ...
    when  0 then ...
    when  1 then ...
  end
```

Comment: Using `SIGN` for this was necessary when all we had was `DECODE`, but with `CASE`, I think it just makes the code less clear.  You can simply write out the comparison: `CASE WHEN a>b THEN ... WHEN a=b THEN ... WHEN a<b THEN ... END`.

Comment: Possibly so, in particular if the comparison is very brief (a > b) ... I should think that SIGN() would then be more useful if you had some awful long expression to work with that you don't want to repeat (for example to work out whether something was before, on, or after, then first day of the fiscal year, which can be a bit workdy) or some expensive function to call to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 10):

There is no boolean types in sql (at least in oracle).
you can use `case`:

```
SELECT CASE when 1 > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM dual
```

But your solution (decode) is also good, read [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1243867216406)

Comment: The SQL standard *does* define a boolean datatype, but - as you correctly mentioned - Oracle SQL does not support it (unlike other DBMS). Inside a PL/SQL procedure you can define boolean variables though.

Answer (score 1):

you can compare two dates with sql

METHOD (1):

```
SELECT   TO_DATE('01/01/2012') - TO_DATE('01/01/2012')  
FROM DUAL--gives zero
```

METHOD (2):

```
SELECT CASE 

when MONTHS_BETWEEN('01/01/2012','01/01/2010') > 0 
THEN 'FIRST IS GREATER' 
ELSE 'SECOND IS GREATER OR EQUAL'  END

 FROM dual
```

sorry i cant format the code the formatting toolbar disappeared ! 
do any one know why?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (CASE 
WHEN (SIGN(actual - target) > 0 ) THEN 
 'NO Bonus for you' 
ELSE 
 'Just made it'  END)
FROM dual
```